# Is there a greasemonkey or similar script or addon for Google Chrome to stop animated GIFs from animating?

Tags: chrome

I am reading a lot of sites, one of them is reddit.

They have some awards you can dole out to comments you like, that all award an icon on the comment itself. Some of these awards, like the "Helpful (Pro) Award" comes bundled with an animated icon.

Given that I have 3 monitors, and I'd like to have a reddit website on one even during my workday, so that when I have 5 minutes to spare I can just glance over to that monitor and keep reading, animated stuff is a bit of an annoyance.

On second thought, animated stuff is a BIG annoyance.

Is there a greasemonkey script, or addon, for Google Chrome (or for any of the browsers really) which would let me block these icons from animating? Hopefully on a per-site basis?

I would rather love Reddit to be a static page that only updates anything when I ask it to. So far my peripheral vision is good enough that animated stuff on any monitor is just continuously grabbing my attention. Which is good, sometimes I keep stuff like monitoring tools for job servers and services on a screen, and it's good that both my eyes and my brain quickly get my attention if something changes.

But for Reddit, I don't care.

Anyone have any advice?

Answer (score 2):

There is a chrome extension called "Animation Policy". You can not change this setting on a per page basis but you can:

- Allow animated images, but only once.
- Disable all image animation.

This extensions can also handle animated svgs.

I know there are some alternatives in the Chrome Web Store. You should see some of them on the Animation Policy page.